# I want to add Gantt chart in my Project (I don't have a start date)

Tags: odoo, project, gantt-chart

The problem is that I don't have a start date on the tasks (how can I Added)

How to add the date_start or are there other solution for that?

[image]

Comment: What about adding a start date field? Sorry, but i don't get your question or your aim. What is the problem? I mean by writing "i don't have a start date" you literally answered your question already.

Comment: The question is how add start_date field

Comment: There should be enough questions or even tutorials on the net answering "how to add a field to an existing odoo model".